# Delphi signature in exe files

Tags: delphi

```
type
  TDelphiSignature=record
    Signature:array [0..3] of LongWord;
    Version:string;
  end;

const
  DelphiSignature:array [0..2] of TDelphiSignature=(
    (Signature:($384F3D26,$B83782C2,$034224F3,$833A9B17);Version:'Delphi Entreprise'),
    (Signature:($235D7823,$19F3A5B6,$0240F343,$C711D126);Version:'Delphi Perso'),
    (Signature:($98DF8CA2,$793A3C7B,$093F7126,$17252A0F);Version:'Delphi Pro')
    // ...
  );
```

The above are version signatures found in Delphi compiled EXE files in the `DVCLAL` resource. I'm looking for other signatures, such as ones for Architect editions, and more importantly, for version numbers (6, 7, 8 ...) that are visible in the resource data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature generated by RAD Studio 2010 Architect is the same one you have for Enterprise.  The DVCLAL resource only tells you the particular Edition of Delphi/BCB used.  Individual Delphi/BCB compiler version numbers are not stored or encoded anywhere in the compiled executable.

**Update:** I found this to be some useful information about the inner working of the DVCLAL resource:

https://assarbad.net/stuff/miscprogs.zip
(in the `\MiscProgs\DVCAL\JeremyRES.html` file)

https://web.archive.org/web/20190107185701/https://wiert.files.wordpress.com/2020/11/miscprogs.zip

Comment: Thanks - « Delphi/BCB compiler version numbers are not stored or encoded anywhere in the compiled executable » ... so there is no way to know the version. This is definitive?

Comment: Pretty much.  About the only way to determine the particular version, AFAIK, is to manually analyze the DFM resources and PE import/export tables looking for version-specific VCL properties and functions.  That is not going to be very reliable.

Comment: Link seems to be dead.

Comment: @LURD and sadly, it looks like the dvclal folder was never captured by the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org) (though the site itself has been). And I can't find any other site that documents the known signatures.

Comment: That file disappeared, it re-appeared at https://assarbad.net/stuff/miscprogs.zip but cannot be archived in the WayBack machine or Archive.is, so I saved it via my blog at https://web.archive.org/web/20190107185701/https://wiert.files.wordpress.com/2020/11/miscprogs.zip Need to take a look at it later.