# How to compile for different product editions?

Tags: delphi

At work, I have Delphi Enterprise, and at home I have Delphi Professional.
My project contains FireDAC connections for Firebird and MS-SQL.

The problem is, FireDAC for MS-SQL is only included in Delphi Enterprise, but not in Delphi Professional.

Now, I would like to add some `ifdef` statements.

Does something like `ifdef PRO` or `ifdef ENT` exist?

Comment: Just don't take work home ;-)

Comment: Or if you have to ask your employer  to grand you Enterprise licence for Delphi. I mena if you are working for them they should provide you with needed means to work for them.

Answer (score 1):

Edition-based conditionals do not exist **at compile-time**. If you need that, you will have to create separate projects (or at least multiple [build configurations](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Build_Configurations_Overview) in a single project) that define their own conditions, and then you can `{$IFDEF}` on those instead.

However, **at run-time**, you can detect the edition used to compile your app, by having your app's code access the `DVCLAL` (Delphi Visual Component Library Access License) resource that the compiler automatically creates in you executable.  See [Delphi signature in exe files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357485/delphi-signature-in-exe-files) and [What are the list of all possible values for DVCLAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720045/) for more details.